# mysql replace into with SET-syntax overrides all fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query:

```
REPLACE INTO `oxarticles`
SET  
    OXID = '10-1010',  
    oxartnum = '10-1010', 
    oxtitle = 'Dummy',  
    oxprice = '10.000000',  
    oxstock = '100',  
    importstatus = 1"
```

This works so far as expected, but the fields I do not specifiy, are just overwritten with `' '` / empty string. From what I read, should this syntax work identically like the `UPDATE`-command.

Am I missing something? How can I prevent that fields are replaced with '' ?

**Edit 1**

Just to clarify, I can't just use `UPDATE`. I am setting a flag (importstatus) to 0 before every run and during the import to 1. After the import finishes, I delete all articles, which are still on status 0.

// Just for the compeletion, here is the PHP-snippet:

```
while (!feof($this->handle))
    {
        $row = fgetcsv($this->handle, 0, ";");

        $sSql = "REPLACE INTO oxarticles SET "
                . " OXID = '" . $row[0] . "', "
                . " oxartnum = '" . $row[0] . "', "
                . " oxtitle = '" . $row[1] . "', "
                . " oxprice = '" . str_replace(",", ".", $row[4]) . "', "
                . " oxstock = '" .  str_replace(",", ".", $row[5]) . "', "
                . " importstatus = 1";



        // $sSql = "UPDATE oxarticles SET oxtitle ='" . $row[1] . "', oxprice='" . $row[4] . "', oxstock='" . $row[5] . "' WHERE oxartnum ='".$row[0]."'";
        $this->db->execute($sSql);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the mysql documentation:

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the
>   table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE
>   index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted. See
>   Section 13.2.5, “INSERT Syntax”.

In other words, the row is being **deleted** and then inserted, hence your old values aren't staying intact.  Perhaps you could select the original row first, and feed those values back in where appropriate.

Comment: Well, seems like I wasn't paying attention enough. Thank you. Will accept this answer as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 1):

You query will replace old data into new data if you do not provide data for a field it will set to null . If you do not want to loose your data just want to update field use on duplicate key update.

```
If did't found any match it will insert new row
If found it will replace data if provide
```

> INSERT INTO table (id,a,b,c,d,e,f,g) VALUES (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)  ON
>   DUPLICATE KEY
>       UPDATE a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d, e=e, f=f, g=g;